# limiting space used by gb4e and adding language information to the right

Tags: linguistics, gb4e

Often authors provide the language name together with examples. The language name is flushed to the right. This works well with short examples but looks ugly with long examples. The code below produces this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\ea
\gll Das ist ein deutsches Beispiel.\\
     this is a   German    example\\ \hfill(German)
\z

\ea
\gll Das  ist einer dieser sehr langen Sätze, die es im Deutschen gibt.\\
     this is  one   of.these very long sentences that it in.the German gives\\ \hfill(German)
\z

\end{document}
```

[image]

What would be better is having some way to limit the space gb4e is taking and having the language aligned at the top of what gb4e does.

Like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two minipages are sufficient.

[image: minipages]

(eg 2)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

%\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\longexampleandlanguage}[2]{
%\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}X@{}p{\widthof{(#2)}}@{}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-1em-\widthof{(#2)}}
#1
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\widthof{(#2)}}
 (#2)
\end{minipage}

%\end{tabularx}
}


\begin{document}


\ea
\gll Das ist ein deutsches Beispiel.\\
     this is a   German    example\\ \hfill(German)
\z

\lipsum[1][1-4]


\ea
\longexampleandlanguage{
    \gll Das  ist einer dieser   sehr langen Sätze,    die  es in der a b deutschen Sprache gibt.\\
         this is  one   of.these very long   sentences that it in the a b German    language gives\\
}{German}
\z

\lipsum[1][1-4]




\end{document}
```

---

A generic command `\glnote` can be defined in expl3 to take a multi-line first argument; and expl3 can also handle the width calculation, so `calc` package does not need to be loaded either.

[image: glnote]

(both egs)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse} % now part of the kernel


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \glnote } { +m m } { 
    % 1==data
    % 2==note
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { ( #2 ) }
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box  }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { \textwidth-4em-\l_tmpa_dim }
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpb_dim}
            #1
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dim_use:N \l_tmpa_dim}
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
\end{minipage}

}
\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

B:

\ea
\glnote{\gll Das ist ein deutsches Beispiel.\\
     this is a   German    example\\
     }{German}
\z

\lipsum[1][1-4]


\ea
\glnote{
    \gll Das  ist einer dieser   sehr langen Sätze,    die  es in der a b deutschen Sprache gibt.\\
         this is  one   of.these very long   sentences that it in the a b German    language gives\\
}{German}
\z

\lipsum[1][1-4]




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer. Maybe it is too complicated, but it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\longexampleandlanguage}[2]{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{}X@{}p{\widthof{(#2)}}@{}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-1em}
#1
\end{minipage} & (#2)\\
\end{tabularx}}


\begin{document}


\ea
\gll Das ist ein deutsches Beispiel.\\
     this is a   German    example\\ \hfill(German)
\z

\lipsum[1][1-4]


\ea
\longexampleandlanguage{
    \gll Das  ist einer dieser   sehr langen Sätze,    die  es in der a b deutschen Sprache gibt.\\
         this is  one   of.these very long   sentences that it in the a b German    language gives\\
}{German}
\z

\lipsum[1][1-4]




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This works much better than your original version.

Answer (score 1):

The tradeoff here is between automatic line wrapping of the long example versus manual intervention. Your solution involves a lot of markup in order to preserve the automatic wrapping of the example. I would go in the other direction and manually split the example where you want it so that the language name annotation fits without extra markup.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}


\begin{document}


\ea
\gll Das ist ein deutsches Beispiel.\\
     this is a   German    example\\ \hfill(German)
\z

\ea
\gll Das  ist einer dieser sehr langen Sätze,\\ 
     this is  one   of.these very long sentences\\ \hfill(German)
\sn \gll die es im Deutschen gibt.\\
    that it in.the German gives\\
\z

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: But this would not be copy & paste safe. It depends on the line width. When I started working with glossed examples, I had a style with wich one had to do the linebreak by hand. I was very relieved when gb4e came around.